# Check if multiple strings are empty or not without using if and when

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on android studio and I got a function that gets the values from different EditText.

```
fun changeUserAccount(
    userName: String,
    password: String,
    confirmPassword: String,
    realName: String,
    accountEmail: String,
    applicationContext: Context
) {


}
```

I need to check if these strings are empty and if possible, which of them is. Except for the creation of different "if" cases or a "when", which is the best and most optimal way to do that?

Comment: Use `isEmpty()` for example: `userName.isEmpty()`

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-empty.html

Comment: But anyway you need to check them one by one, I want to know if it's possible to check them all at once.

Comment: Why are you interested in doing this?

Comment: Compact code, efficiency,and understandable code.

Comment: For compact and understandable code you can use a method that do all checks you needs.
For the efficiency you cannot do better than check all variables one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make one generic function to check all string are valid or not.

You can take n number of strings as **vararg** and can check each of them by making one util or extension function.

Here is Util class

```
object StringUtils {

fun isAllValid(vararg args: String?) : Boolean {

    //checking all strings passed and if a single string is not valid returning false.
    args.forEach {
        if(isNotValid(it))
            return false
    }
    return true
}

fun isValid(string: String?): Boolean {
    return string != null && string.isNotEmpty() && string.isNotBlank()
}

fun isNotValid(string: String?) : Boolean {
    return isValid(string).not()
}

}
```

and you can use like this

```
fun changeUserAccount(
        userName: String,
        password: String,
        confirmPassword: String,
        realName: String,
        accountEmail: String,
        applicationContext: Context
    ) {

        //You can pass n number of strings.
        val isAllStringsValid = StringUtils.isAllValid(userName,password,confirmPassword,realName,accountEmail)

       //this returns true
       StringUtils.isAllValid("hi","how","are","you","?")


       //this returns false
       StringUtils.isAllValid("","how","are","you","?")


       //this returns false
       StringUtils.isAllValid(null,"how","are","you","?")


       //this returns false
       StringUtils.isAllValid("","how","are","you","?")
    }
```

Comment: But anyway you need to check them one by one, I want to know if it's possible to check them all at once. It is possible?

Comment: yes, we can.I have some idea. I'll try and update if it is working

Comment: If you need to check which parameter is not valid, you can use return type one data class which will have one string and one boolean. and you can pass return the data class with boolean false and a string that was not valid.